# I messed with the git remote url and now it is giving the following error

Tags: php, git, github, ssh

I messed with the git remote url and now it is giving the following error:

fatal: remote error:   You can't push to git://github.com/ssh-iitmandi/InventoryManager.git   Use https://github.com/ssh-iitmandi/InventoryManager.git

Comment: try: git remote set-url origin https:// github.com/ssh-iitmandi/InventoryManager.git

Comment: I tried doing both mentioned method but now it gives permission denied (publickey) error

Answer (score 1):

try removing existing origin then add it again

```
  git remote rm origin
  git remote add origin git@github.com:user/repo.git
  git push origin master
```